# Python: different (excel) file names, same content check

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, compare, docx

Q: Using Python, how can one test if two differently named Excel files have the same content?

What I've tried: most answers I've seen suggest filecmp.cmp or hash. I've tried using both, but without success. In particular, suppose 'f1.xlsx' has only two non-empty cells: A1 = 'hello' and B1 = 'world'. Next, copy and paste this content to a new file 'f2.xlsx'. Both files now have exactly two non-empty entries in the same exact cell locations. I get the following results:

```
>> f1 = 'f1.xlsx'
>> f2 = 'f2.xlsx'

#Using read():
>>> open(f1).read()==open(f2).read()
False

#Using filecmp.cmp:
>>> filecmp.cmp(f1, f2, shallow=True)
False

#Using izip:
>>> all(line1 == line2 for line1, line2 in izip_longest(f1, f2))
False

#Using hash:
>>> hash1=hashlib.md5()
>>> hash1.update(f1)
>>> hash1 = hash1.hexdigest()
>>> hash2=hashlib.md5()
>>> hash2.update(f2)
>>> hash2 = hash2.hexdigest()
>>> hash1==hash2
False

#also note, using getsize:
>>> os.path.getsize(f1)
8007
>>> os.path.getsize(f2)
8031
```

Certainly I could use Pandas to interpret the Excel files as dataframes, and then return True using standard comparisons such as all(), but I was hoping there would be a better way, e.g. that would also work on .docx files.

Thanks in advance! I suspect the knot is in using extensions like .xlsx or .docx in 'standard' tests, but hope there is an efficient way to compare content nonetheless.

Note: if it simplifies the problem, order does not matter so that if f2 had A1 = 'world' and B1 = 'hello', I'd want "True" returned.

Comment: I would unzip the content and try to use xmldiff package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmldiff on subset of files. You may have to get rid of the open xml noise (e.g. rsid). I am not sure how it works in excel, but docx has a markup simplifier http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/04/22/141825.aspx, which can be applied before doing a comparison. Warning: the simplifier is C#.

Comment: thanks! unzipping makes sense. my current-working-solution is to use python's xlrd when a file has '.xl' in it

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in the past and in the end have just made some 'line by line' comparisons. For excel files I use the openpyxl module which has a great interface for digging through the files cell by cell. For the docx I used the python_docx module. The following code works for me:

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> from docx import Document

>>> f1 = Document('testDoc.docx')
>>> f2 = Document('testDoc.docx')
>>> wb1 = load_workbook('testBook.xlsx')
>>> wb2 = load_workbook('testBook.xlsx')
>>> s1 = wb1.get_active_sheet()
>>> s2 = wb2.get_active_sheet()

>>> def comp_xl(s1, s2):
>>>    for row1, row2 in zip(s1.rows, s2.rows):
>>>         for cell_1, cell_2 in zip(row1, row2):
>>>             if isinstance(cell_1, openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell):
>>>                 continue
>>>             elif not cell_1.value == cell_2.value:
>>>                 return False
>>>    return True

>>> comp_xl(s1, s2)
True
>>> all(cell_1.value==cell_2.value for cell_1, cell_2 in zip((row for row in s1.rows), (row for row in s2.rows)) if isinstance(cell_1, openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell)) 
True

>>> def comp_docx(f1, f2):
>>>     p1 = f1.paragraphs
>>>     p2 = f2.paragraphs
>>>     for i in range(len(p1)):
>>>         if p1[i].text == p2[i].text:
>>>             continue
>>>         else: return False
>>>     return True

>>> comp_docx(f1, f2)
True
>>> all(line1.text == line2.text for line1, line2 in zip(f1.paragraphs, f2.paragraphs))
True
```

It is pretty basic and obviously doesn't take into account the styles or formatting but for just testing the text contents of both files it works. Hope this helps someone.